# Losing message when using multicast in local machine

Tags: java, multicast

I wrote a java program that is able to send/receive messages via a multicast address.
My code for multicast sender:

```
public boolean multicastSender(DataTransferObject message) {

        try {

            InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            MulticastSocket s = new MulticastSocket(port);
            s.joinGroup(group);

            String msg = jsh.dtoToJsonString(message);
            DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(
                    msg.getBytes(), msg.length(), group, port);
            s.send(data);

            s.leaveGroup(group);
            return true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My code for multicast receiver:

```
public DataTransferObject multicastReceiver() {
    try {
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
        MulticastSocket s = new MulticastSocket(port);
        s.joinGroup(group);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000 * 1024];
        DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        String jsonData;
        DataTransferObject dto;
        while (true) {
            s.receive(data);
            jsonData = new String(buffer, 0, data.getLength());
            dto = jsh.dtoFromJson(jsonData);

            if (dto == null) {
                continue;
            } else {

                return dto;

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

My program has 4 parallel threads that listen and receive messages from four different multicast addresses (224.0.0.[1->4]) and ports [66601->66604]. In the test, I run two programs at the same time to test the communication between them. Yet I discovered that sometimes, program A sends a message to a multicast address, in a correct case, A will also receive it and so will B. But sometimes, I see that A announced that it sent the message but after that, neither A or B receive it again. I run the test on my local machine (Mac OS 10.9 with core 2 duo) . Should this problem because of my computer or something else? 

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen in a Windows environment.  I understand that it's because the network layer is separate from the JVM.

What this means is one JVM may read and process/discard this message, yet other JVM's won't read the same message as the network layer has already delivered the UDP message to the first consumer, no matter how many JVM's have subscribed to the same group.  This may or may not be a bug in the operating system - it's very subjective.   Personally I think the OS should track registrants in order to replicate the delivery, as that's the intention of clients - it's a bit misleading to think otherwise given that an application is joining a group to receive multicasts.  The operating system should take this into consideration.

I have come to this conclusion through empirical evidence, and may not be true for other platforms.

Comment: Do you have any references to support this claim?

Comment: This was a looong time ago.   I can say with hand on heart that I experienced this.   The TCP stack doesn't guarantee at-least-once delivery for every process - the packet stays in a buffer, until someone receives it or more data arrives and the packet is evicted.
It makes complete sense that the delivery of a packet means that the comns layer in the OS doesn't need to hold on to it for other processes/tasks/threads.    Suggest you try it out for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

UDP, which I guess underlies your multicast implementation, does not guarantee delivery. The receiver or network will drop packets when overloaded. You'll need a higher-level protocol to ensure delivery (google reliable multicast).

Comment: Over localhost? C'mon get real....this is a copout answer. Sure it's true that Multicast delivery is not guaranteed, but that's due to packet collision or route termination or something of the sort, which shouldn't happen on localhost. Multicast packet drop should be slim-to-none over localhost.

Comment: Unfortunately not, from what I remember from seven years ago it also happens on localhost if your implementation isn't draining it fast enough (ie sender is faster than receiver) and the receive buffer is full.

Comment: What you're talking about has nothing to do with Multicast and has to do with layer 7 implementation details. That has nothing to do with why 'UDP is lossy'. You're talking about a faulty application. When people talk about Multicast transmissions not being guaranteed, they're talking about network issues and the sender and receiver not guaranteeing things between each other, such as the ACKs that TCP have.

Comment: It's not an application space issue. UDP does not have a mechanism to "throttle" the sender as TCP as you pointed out. What is the receiving socket implementation supposed to do if the application code is too slow to drain the receive buffer? Something has to be lost be definition in this scenario.

Comment: Again, you literally just described in your explanation that the the application is faulty. `What is the receiving socket implementation supposed to do if the application code is too slow`. This is an application space issue, not a network issue. You have incorrectly labeled an application space issue as a network issue, and it's not the fault of the loopback interface. I stand by my -1.

Comment: We're splitting hairs here. The original question has 4 threads running at full blast, and with OS scheduling it is very likely to get in a situation where the recv is does not get enough time to drain the socket. Sure this is not a fault of the loopback implementation, but from the applications POV, there are dropped UDP packets. In a realistic application scenario this happens and can't be avoided by the application. My statement was 'UDP does not guarantee delivery', and whether that's caused by the loopback interface or a full recv buffer is irrelevant for the app developer here.